# AmplifyJS , remove a stored object

Tags: amplifyjs

I started using amplifijs and I successfully stored and retrieved my objects in the storage, but I don't know ho to remove them by name.

I used this syntax:

```
amplify.store("name",{valName1:"val1", ...});
var storage = amplify.store("name");
var val1 = storage.valName1;
```

How can I remove them by name like?

```
amplify.remove("name");
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the answer :

```
amplify.store("name",null);
```